# X.Org does not work with a lowlatency kernel

Tags: kernel, xorg

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 with the 3.13.0-74-generic linux kernel, but I would like to use a lowlatency kernel. I have installed it using:

`sudo apt-get install linux-image-lowlatency`

And I have tried to boot it. The problem arises when I try to start the GUI: if I try to login using the login start screen as usual, it enters a loop, showing time after time the login screen. If I try to `startx` from the command line, I get an error similar to this:

```
X.Org X Server
{...}
Build Operative System: 3.13.0-74-generic
Current Operative System: 3.13.0-74-lowlatency
{...}
modprobe ERROR: could not find module by name='nvidia_340'
```

I would like to be able to boot the lowlatency kernel in my installation without messing anything in the X.Org server. What should I do to avoid this error? Should I reinstall the X.Org server? If I do that, would it continue working with the old generic kernel?

**Update:** I have followed the steps here https://askubuntu.com/a/581842/175994, installing before following the steps the `linux-headers` of the lowlatency kernel. It solves the problem in the lowlatency kernel, but, after that, it does not work in the generic kernel. Is there an easy way to have the two of them working?

Comment: think this is a duplicate of this - you'll need to remove the nvidia driver installation - http://askubuntu.com/questions/564627/startx-fails-could-not-find-module-by-name-nvidia-304

Comment: I have followed the steps there, without solving anything. The same error appears now if I boot the generic kernel. I got this warning while installing: Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.

Comment: Well then install the kernel source.

Comment: Done. Now it's working with the low latency kernel. I will keep open the question while I try to make it work with both kernels. Thank you for the two comments.